# Join team, city, and schedules table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables:

teams, cities, and schedules

Fields:

```
teams: teamid, cityid, and teamname
city: cityid, cityname, stateid
scheduless: teamid, oppteamid
```

I can currently join the schedules and team tables with the following SQL

```
SELECT t1.teamname, t1.cityid, t2.teamname, t2.cityid, COUNT( t2.cityid ) 
FROM schedules s
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON s.teamid = t1.teamid
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON s.oppteamid = t2.teamid
GROUP BY t2.cityid
```

Which gives me the teamname where the team is going to play.

How can add an additional join to get the cityname where the team is going to play.

I've Tried:

```
SELECT t1.teamname, t1.cityid, c1.cityname t2.teamname, t2.cityid, c2.cityname
FROM schedules s
INNER JOIN teams t1 ON s.teamid = t1.teamid
INNER JOIN city c1 ON c1.cityid = t1.cityid
INNER JOIN teams t2 ON s.oppteamid = t2.teamid
INNER JOIN city c2 ON c2.cityid = t2.cityid
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon, I just updated with my try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take these tables as an example:

```
create table teams (teamid int, cityid int, teamname varchar(100));
insert into teams values (1, 1, 'Chicagoans'), (2, 2, 'Dallasfolks'), (3, 3, 'Huskonians');

create table city (cityid int, cityname varchar(100), stateid char(2));
insert into city values (1, 'Chicago', 'IL'), (2, 'Dallas', 'TX'), (3, 'Lincoln', 'NE');

create table scheduless(teamid int, oppteamid int);
insert into scheduless values (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3);
```

You could use a query like this, assuming that scheduless's teamid is the team that is hosting the event.

```
select 
  t.teamname as hometeam,
  t.cityid as homecity,
  c.cityname as homecityname,
  opp.teamname as opponent,
  opp.cityid as opponentcity,
  copp.cityname as opponentcityname,
  count(*) as number_of_games
from scheduless s
inner join teams t on s.teamid = t.teamid
inner join teams opp on s.oppteamid = opp.teamid
inner join city c on t.cityid = c.cityid
inner join city copp on opp.cityid = copp.cityid
group by 
  t.teamname,
  t.cityid,
  c.cityname,
  opp.teamname,  
  opp.cityid,
  copp.cityname;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
| hometeam    | homecity | homecityname | opponent    | opponentcity | opponentcityname | number_of_games |
+-------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Chicagoans  |        1 | Chicago      | Dallasfolks |            2 | Dallas           |               1 |
| Chicagoans  |        1 | Chicago      | Huskonians  |            3 | Lincoln          |               1 |
| Dallasfolks |        2 | Dallas       | Huskonians  |            3 | Lincoln          |               1 |
+-------------+----------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot